# React and Tailwind CSS - switching sticky class on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

In my React page, there is an element, `Block-2` positioned as `sticky`. When my scroll crosses the `#block3` element, I would like to remove `sticky` class. When the user scrolls up and `#block3` is visible in the scroll area again, the `sticky` class should be reapplied.

For Tailwind CSS, I'm not able to determine the correct way to do this, since the classnames fall under a direct element.

How can I handle this?

**My React Page:**

```
    // Dependencies
    import React from "react";
    
    // Styles
    import "./tailwind.output.css";
    
    const App = () => {
      const handleScroll = (event) => {
        //how to achieve the goal?
        console.log(event.currentTarget.scrollTop);
        console.log(event.currentTarget.offsetHeight);
      };
    
      return (
        <div
          onScroll={handleScroll}
          className="overflow-y-auto flex flex-wrap gap-4 h-screen border-solid border-4 border-indigo-600"
        >
          <div className="sticky bg-gray-500 top-0 z-30 h-[32rem] border-solid border-4 border-orange-600 ">
            Block-2
          </div>
          <div
            id="block3"
            className="h-[22rem] border-solid border-4 border-green-600 "
          >
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the
            readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of
            using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of
            letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it
            look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web
            page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a
            search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
            infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by
            accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
          </div>
          <div className="h-[32rem] grow border-solid border-4 border-gray-600 ">
            Block-3
          </div>
          <div>Last child</div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

**Demo:**

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hill-egf7fq?file=/src/App.js:0-1525)

Comment: The code would be a bit long to write, but I guess you will need to use `ref` on `block3`  to get the position, and the use it to remove or add classes

Comment: @John, I am highly confused to get the right way. need any sample or my `codepen` updated

Comment: I tried to update your code, but can't test it. Tell me if it helps https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-rumple-hke5p1

Comment: I see it, for me sticky not removed. it's always same. when will it removed? when green border reached on scroll the sticky need to removed

Comment: When this condition is true "if (scrollTop + containerHeight > block3Top)"